# What is the proper way to comment functions in Python?

Tags: python

Is there a generally accepted way to comment functions in Python? Is the following acceptable?

```
#########################################################
# Create a new user
#########################################################
def add(self):
```

Comment: In summary - use a docstring immediately AFTER the function definition.

Answer (score 454, accepted):

The correct way to do it is to provide a docstring. That way, `help(add)` will also spit out your comment.

```
def add(self):
    """Create a new user.
    Line 2 of comment...
    And so on... 
    """
```

That's three double quotes to open the comment and another three double quotes to end it. You can also use any valid Python string. It doesn't need to be multiline and double quotes can be replaced by single quotes.

See: [PEP 257](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/)

Comment: Note that it doesn't have to be triple-quoted; any string literal will work. But you can put more information in a multiline string.

Comment: Though convention dictates that it should be triple-quoted. I've never seen a docstring that wasn't.

Comment: Which is not to say that I don't agree.  They should be triple quoted, but you will see some in the wild that aren't.

Comment: You can also use three single-quotes (rather than three double-quotes) to open and close the docstring.

Comment: shouldn't you indent the comment as well?

Comment: @ChinmayKanchi According to [PEP 8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#documentation-strings) the last triple-quote should be on its own line.

Comment: See also [PEP 257 -- Docstring Conventions](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/).

Comment: The link appears to be broken, and the code sample is invalid (it throws an `IndentationError`)...

Comment: @CraigMcQueen there is a difference between single and double quote, double qutoe is ignored during the compiling process - so you should use double instead of single quotes

Comment: @nuemlouno: There is *no* difference; `''' doc string '''` and `""" doc string """` do *exactly* the same thing, aside from the extremely limited case of which run of three quote characters you'd need to escape. Both of them compile to the same string literal, both are attached to the function or class as the associated docstring in the exact same way.

Answer (score 117):

Use [docstrings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/).

This is the built-in suggested convention in [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) for describing function using docstring comments:

```
def test_function(p1, p2, p3):
    """
    test_function does blah blah blah.

    :param p1: describe about parameter p1
    :param p2: describe about parameter p2
    :param p3: describe about parameter p3
    :return: describe what it returns
    """ 
    pass
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be indented (after the line with `def`)? (Not a rhetorical question.)

Comment: I like this style but when I hover over my function all I get is args -> <return type> it does not show any of the descriptive information, any ideas?

Comment: @RicardoSanchez In which IDE do you get this style? VS code usually displays everything after hovering and Pycharm does not display anything if you hover.

Comment: @ShwetabhShekhar I just checked again and it does works on VSCode, it must has been after an update, thank you.

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA gives a "Loose punctuation mark." warning

Comment: Another notable thing could be [PEP 287 – reStructuredText Docstring Format](https://peps.python.org/pep-0287/). Good documentation can be written through [reStructuredText](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/rst.html)

Comment: Do note that since the introduction of [typing](https://peps.python.org/pep-0484/) you can skip over the params and return values in the comment and simply describe the function's behaviour, PyCharm understands type hints.

It also makes for cleaner code. Personally, I wouldn't type hint every variable but for functions, it makes sense to do so.

Answer (score 30):

Use a docstring, as others have already written.

You can even go one step further and add a [doctest](http://docs.python.org/library/doctest.html?highlight=doctest#module-doctest) to your docstring, making automated testing of your functions a snap.

Comment: This answer is quite weak without following through to the linked page.

Answer (score 22):

Use a [docstring](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/):

> A string literal that occurs as the first statement in a module, function, class, or method definition. Such a docstring becomes the `__doc__` special attribute of that object.
>
> All modules should normally have docstrings, and all functions and classes exported by a module should also have docstrings. Public methods (including the `__init__` constructor) should also have docstrings. A package may be documented in the module docstring of the `__init__.py` file in the package directory.
>
> String literals occurring elsewhere in Python code may also act as documentation. They are not recognized by the Python bytecode compiler and are not accessible as runtime object attributes (i.e. not assigned to `__doc__` ), but two types of extra docstrings may be extracted by software tools:
>
> 1. String literals occurring immediately after a simple assignment at the top level of a module, class, or `__init__` method are called "attribute docstrings".
> 2. String literals occurring immediately after another docstring are called "additional docstrings".
>
> Please see [PEP 258](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0258) , "Docutils Design Specification" [[2]](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/#id5) , for a detailed description of attribute and additional docstrings...

Answer (score 12):

The principles of good commenting are fairly subjective, but here are some guidelines:

- Function comments should describe the **intent** of a function, not the implementation
- Outline any assumptions that your function makes with regards to system state. If it uses any global variables (tsk, tsk), list those.
- Watch out for excessive [ASCII art](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII_art). Having long strings of hashes may seem to make the comments easier to read, but they can be annoying to deal with when comments change
- Take advantage of language features that provide 'auto documentation', i.e., docstrings in Python, POD in Perl, and Javadoc in Java

Comment: there is nothing subjective about this, Python is very clear about using Docstring commenting.

Comment: @fuzzy lollipop, I appreciate the comment, but you'll note that my last point makes that exact point. Perhaps the OP's question is only about the mechanics of commenting in Python, but I don't think my answer warrants down-voting

Answer (score 8):

I would go for a documentation practice that integrates with a documentation tool such as **[Sphinx](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/)**.

The first step is to use a `docstring`:

```
def add(self):
 """ Method which adds stuff
 """
```

Answer (score 7):

Read about using [docstrings](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0257/) in your Python code.

As per the Python *docstring conventions*:

> The docstring for a function or method should summarize its behavior and document its arguments, return value(s), side effects, exceptions raised, and restrictions on when it can be called (all if applicable). Optional arguments should be indicated. It should be documented whether keyword arguments are part of the interface.

There will be no golden rule, but rather provide comments that mean something to the other developers on your team (if you have one) or even to yourself when you come back to it six months down the road.

Answer (score 2):

I would go a step further than just saying "use a docstring". Pick a documentation generation tool, such as pydoc or epydoc (I use epydoc in pyparsing), and use the markup syntax recognized by that tool.  Run that tool often while you are doing your development, to identify holes in your documentation.  In fact, you might even benefit from writing the docstrings for the members of a class *before* implementing the class.

Answer (score 1):

While I agree that this should not be a comment, but a docstring as most (all?) answers suggest, I want to add [**numpydoc** (a docstring style guide)](https://www.numpy.org/devdocs/docs/howto_document.html).

If you do it like this, you can (1) automatically generate documentation and (2) people recognize this and have an easier time to read your code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use three quotes to do it.

You can use single quotes:

```
def myfunction(para1,para2):
  '''
  The stuff inside the function
  '''
```

Or double quotes:

```
def myfunction(para1,para2):
  """
  The stuff inside the function
  """
```

Answer (score 1):

You can go one step further and document the rest of your method.

This may be a bit much at times, but in certain situations, it will help the use and understanding of your code(for example, if you are developing a public API, etc).

Like this;

```
def get_most_recent_filename(dir:str, prefix:str, extension:str) -> str:
    """
    Get the most recent filename in a directory matching a specified prefix and extension.

    Parameters
    ----------
    dir : str
        The directory in which to search for files.
    prefix : str
        The desired prefix of the file name.
    extension : str
        The desired file extension (e.g., '.txt').

    Returns
    -------
    str
        The full path to the most recent file matching the criteria, 
    or None if no matching files are found.

    Description
    -----------
    This function searches the specified directory for files with a 
    given prefix and extension. 
    It returns the full path to the most recent file that matches 
    the criteria, allowing you to easily access or process the most 
    recent file in a directory.

    If no matching files are found or if the directory does not exist, 
    the function returns None.

    Examples
    --------
    >>> get_most_recent_filename("/path/to/directory", "data_", ".csv")
    '/path/to/directory/data_20231030.csv'
    >>> get_most_recent_filename("/nonexistent_directory", "file_", ".txt")
    'Directory not found: [/nonexistent_directory]'
    """
    # and here goes the function logic ...
```

ps; this follows the [numpy docstring conventions](https://numpydoc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/format.html#docstring-standard)

Answer (score 0):

The correct way is as follows:

```
def search_phone_state(phone_number_start,state,dataframe_path,separator):  
   """
   returns records whose phone numbers begin with a phone_number_start and are from state
   """
   dataframe = pd.read_csv(filepath_or_buffer=dataframe_path, sep=separator, header=0)
   return dataframe[(pd.Series(dataframe["Phone"].values.tolist()).str.startswith(phone_number_start, na="False"))& (dataframe["State"]==state)]
```

If you do:

```
help(search_phone_state)
```

It will print:

```
Help on function search_phone_state in module __main__:

search_phone_state(phone_number_start, state, dataframe_path, separator)
returns records whose phone numbers begin with a phone_number_start and are from state
```

Comment: Please translate to English before posting.

Comment: ok, tk you comment