# Is it more efficient to assign objects attributes which are also objects to a variable or call them everytime

Tags: python

I have 2 classes as so:

```
class Status:
    id = 1
    text = "blah"

class User:
    status = StatusObject
```

In my program, I need to get the Status' ID and text.

Which of these two solutions is the more efficient/more accepted?

Solution 1:

```py
status = User.status
id = status.id
text = status.text
```

Solution 2:

```py
id = user.status.id
text = user.status.text
```

thanks!

Comment: Also i know the title is terrible I just didnt know how to phrase it

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [Should I store a calculation in a variable if it will be used a lot?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55542474/should-i-store-a-calculation-in-a-variable-if-it-will-be-used-a-lot)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When accessing a variable or a member of an object, python performs a dictionary lookup (in `locals()`, `globals()`, `class.__dict__` ... you name it)

So with this:

```
id = user.status.id
```

first you're shadowing `id` (which gets IDs of objects) but you're doing 3 dictionary lookups (`user`, `status` and `id`)

Aliasing `user.status` to `status` makes the code slightly faster (*very* slightly with only 2 dict lookups)

This technique is used in an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/480227/6451573) of the famous question [How do you remove duplicates from a list whilst preserving order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480214/how-do-you-remove-duplicates-from-a-list-whilst-preserving-order)

```
def f7(seq):
    seen = set()
    seen_add = seen.add
    return [x for x in seq if not (x in seen or seen_add(x))]
```

`seen_add` is an alias for `seen.add`. Saves one lookup.

In your case, it also makes it easier to read ( because the same pattern isn't repeated several times (and also more "object oriented" since you're defining a context more clearly).

And that's true in all languages (even if compiled languages are able to recognize repeated accesses and alias them in the binary, something python can't do)

Comment: So with ```id = user.status.id``` python is first looking in users dictionary for the status attribute, and then a second search in status' dictionary of attributes for id. Therefore aliasing ```user.status``` to status reduces the number of lookups making it a very small amount faster. Have I understood that correctly?

Comment: yes. Each token means a lookup.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!